# Corona SDK native.newWebView scrolling does not work

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

In my app I created with Corona SDK, I'm adds an operation manual that I have written in html.

I put the `<html>` file in the `resources` folder, and through a `native.newWebView` **can not display** it, the problem, that I can not fix, is that in the web view scrolling does not work for me, so I can not read the entire text html, can anyone help?

The `html` file has the following structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>                    
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, heigth=device-heigth, initial-scale=1 ">
      <title>jQuery Mobile - Backbone.js and Require.js Apps</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
      <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css"> 
             html {    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;  }
             </style> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css" type="text/css"   charset="utf-8"/>
   <body >
      <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" data-quicklinks="false">
         <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content" id="conts">
            <h1> Title/h1>
            <h3>
                </h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div><!-- /content -->
         </div><!-- /page -->
      </body> 
  </html>
```

The WebView I create in the following way:

```
webView = native.newWebView( display.contentWidth*0.6, display.pixelHeight*0.16,  display.pixelWidth*0.5, display.pixelHeight*0.3);
webView.hasBackground = false;
webView:request( "assets/were/Manual/myfile.html", system.ResourceDirectory );
```

I hope someone can help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Seems as an incorrect **`vieport`** setup

Try to repair syntax in defining `<meta...>` to match the supported syntax-options

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, heigth=device-heigth, ...=1 ">
<!-- correct                                           ^^            ^^       ^
                                                       ||            ||       | TYPO(s)
                                                       vv            vv       X  REPAIR(s)  -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, ...=1">
```